# Reposition texture in real time

Tags: three.js, textures

Is it possible in THREE JS to re-position a texture in real time?

I have a model of a heart and I'm projecting "color maps"/"texture with colors" onto the model but the position of the maps can be a little different each time.

**UPDATE**

More info:

I have about 20 color maps. They are 80 by 160 pixels. I need to position them on the model. The position of the color maps may differ slightly. Currently I add all the color maps to a big texture and then I load the texture onto the model. That all works just fine.

But sometimes a surgeon feels like a color map needs to be moved over or rotated a little. I can't expect him to change the hard-coded locations in the code. I want him to be able to drag the color map to the right location.

I studied the THREE JS documentation and examples but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Is `mesh.material.map.offset.x += 0.001;` what you are referring to?

Comment: @WestLangley Not exactly was I was looking for but it may help. Thank you.